# Why is the bound in Radon's Theorem optimal?

Tags: convex-analysis

I have read about Radon's Theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%27s_theorem). The theorem states that

> Any set of $d + 2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be partitioned into two sets whose convex hulls intersect.

I strongly suspect that the bound $d+2$ is even optimal, i.e. the statement above is not true for $\widetilde{d} < d+2$. This is easy to see in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I do not see why this is also true for higher dimensions. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Consider a set of basis vectors plus the origin. Any partition of this set in two subsets is separated by a linear inequality.

Comment: I am sorry but I can not follow you. We have to examine an ARBITRARY set of  $d+1$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, so why do you consider such a set?

Comment: The fact that there's a particular set of $d+1$ points can not be partitioned into two sets whose convex hulls intersect means that the statement with $d+2$ changed to $d+1$ is not true.

Comment: @WimC: OK, I can intuitively see that this works, but is there a way to prove this in a formal way? Do you use the Separation Theorem here? How do we know that the convex hulls implied by the partition are compact and disjoint ?